# EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash: self.x vs _x

Tags: objective-c, properties, exc-bad-access

The following code does not crash

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    _heading = newHeading.trueHeading;
    NSLog(@"heading - %.2f", newHeading.trueHeading);
    //NSLog(@"Updating heading - %f", newHeading.trueHeading);
}
```

where as this one does

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    self.heading = newHeading.trueHeading;
    NSLog(@"heading - %.2f", newHeading.trueHeading);
    //NSLog(@"Updating heading - %f", newHeading.trueHeading);
}
```

Can someone explain why this is the case? The property looks like:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) float heading;
```

Also it is never initialized in the init method because I don't want to store a value until it is right. Right now it is:

```
- (id) initUser
{
    return [self init];
}
```

Comment: Have you `@synthesize`'d your property?

Comment: I would guess he did either that or provided the methods, otherwise it wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

After you declare a property, you should use `@synthesize` to tell the compiler to generate a getter and setter method. By default, these methods are named foo and setFoo, where foo is a name of the variable. Also, by default, the variable represented by the property has the same name as a property, unless you change this with @synthesize foo=_foo to use to a different named instance variable.

Comment: Sort of correct. If you don't use `@synthesize` you need to provide your own [accessors](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/AccessorMethod.html) that conform to [KVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH25-SW1)